# SQL Full Text Indexing, ASCII control characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ascii, full-text-search

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Full text indexing. I noticed that some results from my search are not included in the result. On further investigation I found that the suspected data contains ASC II control characters (http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/escape-ascii-code-27.html). My table is in a simple flat structure and if any row contains one of those characters, the results are not displayed.

As soon as I replace the character in the data, the result appears. I am using CONTAINS in the query.

I could not find a link that confirms this behaviour. I can remove those characters from the database, but would be nice to have confirmation and understanding of the reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue. On investigating the full text crawl log I found the database size was reached (it is express edition). After doing some clean up all the rows are being returned properly.
The link that helped me in troubleshooting:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142495(v=sql.105).aspx